# High-writes, Occasional Reads (both must be fast), any recipes?

Tags: performance, t-sql, database-performance

I have a 16 GB mem server, single SQL instance, with a max mem (buffer pool) capped at 10 GB. The .net app performs high volume of writes which must be fast (and they are). The writes go into a couple of tables that are partitioned and fast growing. The app exposes UI where users could see the data, but it's occasional. The reads must be reasonably rendered < 2 seconds. My issue is that I feel I've exhausted fine-tuning the reads (am now at ~ 5 seconds but that's slow). I also noticed that the Buffer pool is mostly consumed by the high-volume data of those two tables, and perhaps that's why some of the reads that need data from other tables are slow since SQL has to go to disk?

Is there a design pattern around this kind of load? high volume writes into big tables (millions of rows), and fast reads from those tables and other low-volume tables?

I found no way in SQL server to control the buffer pool by allocating say only 40% to data from the big tables, leaving 60% for other data to keep its hit-ratio high and improve the reads.

Thoughts?

Comment: How do your reads filter the data? Does all queries follow the same pattern?

Comment: The queries do filter data via input params to the SP, mostly using joins and where clauses. The queries do not follow the same pattern, no.

Answer (score 0):

In such situations you should apply partitioning of tables.The partitioning mapped on different filegroups may minimize the disk IO if you are not reading data which is currently being written on disk.